# batch, read texts files in n'th line to m'th line

Tags: text, batch-file

I am new about batch command.

I have five text files in different folders. For example,

```
c:\case1\case1.txt
c:\case2\case2.txt
c:\case3\case3.txt
```

So I want to read these text files from nth line to mth line
and write these values in same text file. How can I make batch files?

For example, the result text file I want is....

case1

```
10456          <--- this valus is in n'th line in case1.txt    
3456           <--- this valus is in n+1'th line in case1.txt    
23455          <--- this valus is in n+2'th = m'th line in case1.txt
```

case2

```
49566          <--- this valus is in n'th line in case2.txt
85494          <--- this valus is in n+1'th line in case2.txt
38566          <--- this valus is in n+2'th = m'th line in case2.txt
```

case3

```
49658          <--- this valus is in n'th line in case3.txt    
48569          <--- this valus is in n+1'th line in case3.txt    
39245          <--- this valus is in n+2'th = m'th line in case3.txt
```

like this.

And important is.... Actually, I really new about batch. So could you write full command not only part of command.

Thankyou very much!!

Answer (score 1):

if you can download stuff, you can use [GNU sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) from line 2 till line 4
example

```
sed -n "2,4p" file
```