# How to include a line of a text file in a batch command?

Tags: windows, batch-file

How exactly do you include a line from a text file in a command in cmd

e.g.

```
Text File1.txt

notepad
firefox
outlook
```

So you can execute a command e.g. start (line number here)

So "start 3" would launch outlook etc

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370523/batch-read-texts-files-in-nth-line-to-mth-line

Answer (score 1):

The following batch script reads and echoes the lines from a text file:

```
for /f "delims=|" %%i in (file1.txt) do @echo %%i
```

The `delims` is necessary if the text lines contain spaces (or anything other than `'|'`, or any other arbitrary but rare character you want).

So you could probably modify the script to execute each line as a command:

```
for /f "delims=|" %%i in (file1.txt) do @start "x" %%i
```

**Note**

You need the double `%%` if you're executing this command within a batch file, but only single `%` if you're executing it directly in a command shell window.

Comment: You can leave the delims argument blank to read a line at a time.  So it'd be `for /f "delims=" ...`